# Unable to install libblkid development library on Ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

Admittedly I'm new to developing on Linux in C.  My goal is to create a small C program to display total diskspace and available on a Raspberry Pi OLED screen.  In trying to learning this, I'm currently developing the portion to read the disk space in Ubuntu installed on a PC.   Reading past questions in stackoverflow, I found someone had recommended to use the libblkid library.  Unfortunately I'm getting an error I could use help deciphering.

I'm installing the package using this command (again, this is for development - is this correct?)

`sudo apt install ./libblkid-dev_2.33.1-0.1_amd64.deb`

The message I receive, verbatim, is:

> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree... Done
> Reading state information... Done
> Note, selecting 'libblkid-dev' instead of './libblkid-dev_2.33.1-0.1_amd64.deb'
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
> or been moved out of Incoming.
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> > The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> > libblkid-dev : Depends: libblkid1 (= 2.33.1-0.1) but 2.37.2-4ubuntu3 is to be installed
> > E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

The package I've download is the AMD64 bit development library from [Debian Package: libblkid-dev (2.33.1-0.1)](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libblkid-dev).

You can see I'm downloading 2.33.1-0.1.   Yet the error seems to state it's dependent on that version but trying to install a newer version 2.3.27-4ubuntu3.

Would appreciate any help offered.

Comment: IMO this question is off-topic here. Ask it on Debian / Linux forum

Comment: I'm trying to install a development library package.   Am I taking the correct approach with this package?  Is there a more up-to-date package I should be using for C in order to retrieve attached drives, total space, space used?   I feel this is more development related.

Comment: Quote : "2.37.2-4ubuntu3 is to be installed" → Seems you have Ubuntu 22.04 and can install with `sudo apt install libblkid-dev` to get the later version **2.37.2** instead of the old downloaded **2.33.1** !!

Comment: WOOT!   I think that was the trick Knud.   Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The availability of libblkid-dev in apt packages was missed.  The correct approach cited by Knud Larsen was to:

`sudo apt install libblkid-dev`

Thank you Knud!